# Rails 4 Link_ to Create New Record - Request Type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, post, get

I am on Rails 4.

Just created a Favorite model & controller in which users can favorite articles. I have it set up so when a user clicks on the link, it routes to the favorite action inside of the favorites_controller. Right now, it is a `get` request, and inside of the action it is simply creating a new favorite.

My question is... is it ok that this is a `get` request? I feel like maybe a `post` request would be better (as forms use post to create things), but since there is no form in this case I decided a `get` request would be fine. Is this ok? or frowned upon?

here is the link_to in my view:

```
<%= link_to favorite_path(title: @article.title, id: @article.id) do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
<% end %>
```

and the action it routes to in the controller:

```
def favorite
    current_user.favorites.create(article_id: params[:id], 
                                  article_title: params[:title])
    flash[:success] = "You added this page to your favorites."
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
end
```

and my routes.rb:

```
get    'favorite'   => 'favorites#favorite'
```

Everything works fine, just want some clarification as to the `get` request and if this is the best way to achieve what I am doing. If there is already documentation on this, please send it my way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you shouldn't use a `get` request to create things or change states.

The reason is simple: Searchengines will follow links and trigger that action. Or some browsers may preload links to speed things up. In both case you will create records although the user never chose to click the link.

Instead just tell Rails to use some javascript to fake a post request (note the `method: :post` part):

```
<%= link_to(favorite_path(title: @article.title, id: @article.id), 
            method: :post) do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
<% end %>
```

Read the [doc about `link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is it necessary to also change `get 'favorite' => 'favorites#favorite'` to `post 'favorite' => 'favorites#favorite'`? @spickermann

Comment: Yes, it is, otherwise you would get a routing error.